# Pandas DataFrame to PostgreSQL using Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, psycopg2

Is it possible to write a Pandas dataframe to PostgreSQL database using psycopg2?

Endgoal is to be able to write a Pandas dataframe to Amazon RDS PostgreSQL instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a SQLAlchemy engine around psycopg2, you could probably use `df.to_sql`. See: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: Thank you, I got SQLAlchemy to work. After using df.to_sql to write is commit necessary?  If so, how would I commit in SQLAlchemy? It appears I need to create a session object then somehow add my query to it and then commit.

Comment: I believe to_sql performs the commit.